# Google Chrome Extension payment option question from non-developer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I came across this forum after some quick Googles. I have hired a developer to make my Chrome Extension and I personally have no experience with this at all.

The extension is up and running with a monthly subscription through Chrome Web Store. I want to add a yearly subscription option so users can choose between the two.

Does anyone know if this can be done? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the source code and basic javascript knowledge?

Comment: Using Chrome Web Store Payments, you can't. In CWS Developer Dashboard, you can choose either monthly subscription or annual subscription, but not both.

Comment: I can get the source code but do not have basic javascript knowledge.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. I figured this was the case but wanted to double check.